# groovy inline shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I have the following shared lib which is used inside a Jenkins pipeline.
I expect the following output when iterating over the list

**firstDestionation

secondDestionation**

instead I get

**[firstDestionation,

secondDestionation]**

I do not understand why this happens. Where is my error?

```
   
    List<String> pushDestination = new ArrayList()
   
    String suffix = ''
    if (config.tagSuffix) {
        suffix = "-$config.tagSuffix"
    }

    if (config.imageTag) {
        List tagList = ParameterUtils.convertParameterToList(this, config.imageTag)
        tagList.each { tag ->
            String fullTag = "$tag$suffix"
            fullTag = fullTag.replace('{commitId}', commitId)

            pushDestination.add("firstDestination")

        }
    }

    if (config.get('createCommitTag', false).toBoolean()) {
        pushDestination.add("secondDestionation")
    }

    container('buildah') {

        sh """

            for currentDestination in ${pushDestination}; do

             echo "currentDestination: \$currentDestination"

            done

        """
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your shell code you have:

```
container('buildah') {
  sh """
      for currentDestination in ${pushDestination}; do
         echo "currentDestination: \$currentDestination"
      done
  """
```

But `${pushDestination}` will be rendered into the string as `[ firstDestination, secondDestination ]`, but bash requires a different syntax for array definitions (ie `(a b c d)`) so you want to render that as the following:

```
   for currentDestination in (${pushDestination.join(" ")}); do
      echo "currentDestination: \$currentDestination"
   done
```